# About Rails Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build model assocation between user and products therefore I tried to user has_many through associations.

However there are more than one type of products.

one user : User.rb

three products : Shoe.rb Shirt.rb Pant.rb and each model has diverse kinds of attributes so I cannot integrate them.

While each user can have many products, products can have only one user.

I already made some mock assocations like below.

User.rb

```
has_many :purchasements
has_many :shoes, through: :purchasements
has_many :shirts, through: :purchasements
has_many :pants, through: :purchasements
```

migration for user

```
nothing more than default
```

Purchasement.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :shoe
belongs_to :shirt
belongs_to :pant
```

migration for purchasement

```
t.belongs_to :user
t.belongs_to :shoe
t.belongs_to :shirt
t.belongs_to :pant
```

Shoe.rb / Shirt.rb / Pant.rb

```
has_one :purchasement
has_one :user, through: :purchasement
```

migration for shoe / shirt / pant

```
nothing more than default
```

I am trying to let users to purchase each products through purchasements model.

purchasement_controller.rb

```
def create
    @shoe = params[:target_shoe] #Could be shoe, shirt or pant
    current_user.shoes << @shoe
    current_user.save
end
```

another try out

```
def create
    @shoe = params[:target_shoe] #Could be shoe, shirt or pant
    shoe_transaction = current_user.purchasements.create
    shoe_transaction.shoe = @shoe
end
```

It's not saving through the middle model, purchasemnets.rb

Where am I missing?

It one gave me an error than I need to save shirt shoe pant altogether.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Why do you have separate models/tables for shoes, shirts and pants? Even though they don't share all of their attributes, it would make your life much easier to have it in the same table. You could also look into something called STI(single table inheritance).

Comment: How can I ahiceve it in one same table for easy life . ?

Comment: The main reason I seperated them is I am not really dealing with products. It's about type of academic paper which should have different logic to show themselves

Comment: also very much of different type of validation jobs..

Comment: Ok, I see. Interesting names for academic papers though :)

Comment: It's Korean name haha

Comment: Thank you for answering Iceman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding it seems you want a user to have purchasements, and you want the purchasements to have the individual items. You also want to link the user directly to the individual items. You're associations should be changed to this:

User.rb (keep the same)

```
has_many :purchasements
has_many :shoes, through: :purchasements
has_many :shirts, through: :purchasements
has_many :pants, through: :purchasements
```

Purchasement.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :shoes
has_many :shirts
has_many :pants
```

Shoe.rb / Shirt.rb / Pant.rb

```
belongs_to :purchasement
belongs_to :user
```

In your database, you're going to need to add data fields `purchasement_id` and `user_id` to Shoe, Shirt and Pant. You should also remove the unnecessary `belongs_to` data fields for for Shoe, Shirt and Pant in the Purchasement data table.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness Russel

Comment: No problem. If this helped you, please accept or upvote my answer. Thanks, happy coding

Comment: how can I save shirt through purchasements

Comment: The shirt will have a user_id and a purchasement_id after checkout if you made the correct database migrations.